# Mutually exclusive AND independent event (help with examples)

Tags: statistics

2 events cannot be mutually exclusive AND independent UNLESS one of the events are impossible.

One example:

> The flipping of a coin details an independent event (flip#1 does not
>   affect flip#2) and a mutually exclusive event (can only be heads or
>   can only be tails), and none of these events are impossible. Am I
>   right? If so, is the theorem wrong?

Another example:

> You can either be a man or a woman. Mutually exclusive (man OR woman,
>   @ birth), and independent (being a man does not affect me being a
>   woman). So this is also also mutually exclusive and independent?

By definition, I understand that mutually exclusive events are events that cannot occur at the same time. In independent events, the probability that one event occurs in no way affects the probability of the other event occurring.

Please provide more examples where there exists mutually exclusive AND independent events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you deal with probability problems, you must use the definitions that are expressed as math (say, set theory) and not as words.

A *(stochastic) experiment* is one that results in exactly one outcome whenever it is performed.  An example of an experiment is to roll a six-sided die and see which side lands up (say, $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$, $x_5$, or $x_6$).  (Note that the outcomes are *mutually exclusive*, a term whose meaning becomes clearer later.)

The set of possible outcomes is called the *sample space*.  For example, $S=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6\}$.

An *event* is a subset of the sample space.  For example, $E_1=\{x_2,x_4,x_6\}$ or $E_2=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$.

A *probability* is a way of assigning a number $P(E)$ to an event $E$ following certain rules ($0\le P(E)\le 1$, the sum of the probabilities of all the outcomes should equal $1$, etc.).  For example, $P(x_1)=P(x_2)=P(x_3)=P(x_4)=P(x_5)=P(x_6)=\frac16$.

The probability of an event is the sum of the probabilities of all its outcomes.  For example, $P(E_1)=P(x_2)+P(x_4)+P(x_6)=\frac12$.

Two events are *independent* if the probability of their intersection is the same as the product of their probabilities.  For example, $E_1\cap E_2=\{x_2\}$ so $P(E_1\cap E_2)=\frac16$.  But $P(E_1)P(E_2)=\frac12\times\frac12=\frac14$ so $E_1$ and $E_2$ are *not* independent.

Two events are *mutually exclusive* if the probability of their union is the same as the sum of their probabilities.  For example, $E_1\cup E_2=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_6\}$ so $P(E_1\cup E_2)=\frac56$.  But $P(E_1)+P(E_2)=\frac12+\frac12=1$ so $E_1$ and $E_2$ are *not* mutually exclusive.

You will note that for two events $A$ and $B$ to be mutually exclusive, they must have no common elements.  If so, then their intersection is the null set.  Thus, $P(A\cap B)=P(\emptyset)=0$ and the only way for the two events to be independent is if $P(A)=0$ or $P(B)=0$.

Comment: Allow me a few minutes to fully digest. All of these answers were very helpful! Thanks to you and everyone that contributed

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing different pairs of events.  "Filip is a man" and "Filip is a woman" are mutually exclusive.  "Filip is a man" and "Robert is a man" are independent.

Comment: Then why not say, "Filip is a man" and "Sarah is a woman"? My question is now, when do you know to introduce another variable, Robert, and where to use it?

Comment: It depends on whom you want to talk about.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these are examples of an event which is: mutual exclusion and independence

> One example:
>
> > The flipping of a coin details an independent event (flip#1 does not affect flip#2) and a mutually exclusive event (can only be heads or can only be tails), and none of these events are impossible. Am I right? If so, is the theorem wrong?

No.  Here, the results of two *different* flips are independent of each other, and *each* individual flip has two mutually exclusive results; heads or tails.

You are not dealing with the same event in each case.

> Another example:
>
> > You can either be a man or a woman. Mutually exclusive (man OR woman, @ birth), and independent (being a man does not affect me being a woman). So this is also also mutually exclusive and independent?

No. The events are mutually exclusive (mostly), but the events are *not* independent.  To see that is so just ask "What is the probability of you being a woman given that you are a man?"

**Alternatively:** Is the probability of being a man *and* a woman equal to the probability of being a man times the probability of being a woman?

---

I have a coin that, when tossed, can land heads-up, heads-up, or on its edge.

However, as it turns out, it never actually lands on its edge.

Also, it has two heads.

So the events of "heads" or "edge" are mutually exclusive.  One can happen, or the other can, but not both.

Still, the events are independent.  The probability of getting both "heads" and "edge" is zero, which is the probability of getting "heads" times the probability of getting "edge".

When $P(A)=1, P(B)=0$, the events $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously mutually exclusive and independent.  $$P(A)+P(B) = 1 ,\quad \therefore \text{mutual exclusion}\\ P(A)P(B)=P(A\cap B) \quad\therefore \text{independent}$$

Comment: "What is the probability of you being a woman given that you are a man?" 0. I don't understand why I can't use this template question for the coins?-"What is the probability of rolling heads given that the coin can be either heads or tails?" I would answer 1/2. EDIT: upon second reading, your answer is starting to make sense. Can you provide an example with and independent AND mutually exclusive event?

Comment: @Filip; I've just taken out *one* coin and tossed it.  What is the probability that it landed tail-up *given* that it has landed head-up?

Comment: 0. I'm just missing an example of both indep and exclusive to fully let it set in. It's common sense, but I seem to have problems discerning what is independent and what isn't

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for examples, here's a rather general one.

Say $X$ is a continuous random variable, and let $I\subset \mathbb{R}:\lambda(I)>0$ (so we have a nondegenerate interval), and let $p\in \mathbb{R}\setminus I$. Then event pairs of the following form are independent and mutually exclusive:

$$A:=\{X\in I\},B:=\{X=p\}$$ because

$$P(A)>0,P(B)=0\implies P(A\cap B)=0=P(A)P(B) \implies P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$$

**Word Example**

Let $A:=$ today's high temperature will be between $10C \text{ and } 15C$, and $B:=$ today's high temperature will be *exactly* 16C.

Answer (score 0):

In words: 2 events are independent if one of the events happening does not affect the probability of the other event happening.

But if 2 events are mutually exclusive, they cannot happen at the same time, so one of the events happening definitely affects the probability of the other event happening (because now the other event cannot happen, whereas it could happen before).  So mutually exclusive events are *never* independent, unless one of the events was impossible to begin with.