# Should joint probabilty of two event be zero if they are independent?

Tags: probability

If two events are independent, there is no overlapping intersection between two probability space. If there are no overlapping should

$$Pr(E \cap F) = 0$$

since event $E$ and $F$ cannot appear together?

I think my intuition is wrong, can someone point out my mistake?

Comment: I believe you have "independent" mixed up with "mutually exclusive".

Comment: Suppose you have  two dice one red and one yellow. In a role, the event that red is 6 is independent from that the yellow is 6, but the intersection of the two events is not empty.

Comment: When one thinks one's intuition is wrong, an option is to have a look at the relevant *definition*, say on WP or in one's textbook.

Answer (score 1):

Events are independent when the way that one resolves is not affected by how the other resolves, which is usually written in a form such as $Pr(A|B) = Pr(A)$. For example, if I roll a die and flip a coin, then knowing the coin flipped heads doesn't change anything about the probabilities of the die roll.

In terms of area of probability space, it's something like this: the fraction of the area of event B that is taken up by event A is the same as the fraction of the whole probability space that is taken up by event A.

On the other hand, you seem to be thinking of what is generally called *mutually exclusive* events. Two events that *cannot* both occur are mutually exclusive. For example, the event of rolling a 6 on a die, and the event of rolling an odd number, are mutually exclusive. It's not hard to see that mutually exclusive events cannot be independent (except in some degenerate circumstances), because by definition $Pr(A|B) = 0 \neq Pr(A)$.

The distinction between the two is pretty important when you're manipulating probabilities, because for independent events, the probability of them both happening is the product of their individual probabilities, i.e. $Pr(A \wedge B) = Pr(A)Pr(B)$, while for mutually exclusive events, the probability of *either* of them happening is the sum of their individual probabilities, i.e. $Pr(A \vee B) = Pr(A) + Pr(B)$, but if you swap the two types of events neither is true.

Answer (score 0):

Independence does not mean that two events cannot occur together. 
Indeed, consider the following example. Throw two regular fair dice. The 
event "throwing 6 with the first die" is independent from the event "throwing 6 with the second die" yet the probability of both events happening is $\frac{1}{36}$. So what is the correct intuition of independence? It tells you that knowledge about some event does not give you any additional information about another event. Consider the following thought experiment (sorry to go so philosophical on you): 
Suppose you were blind folded and stepped into a room. In this room which has area $1$. There are 4 colors on the floor: white, yellow , blue and green (green is what you get when a white spot is painted both yellow and blue).

Let us first consider an example of DEPENDENCE: Suppose you know that there is no overlap between the yellow and blue areas in the room and that they both have area $1/4$ (this means of course that there are no green areas). 
Remember that you are blindfolded, I let you into the room and tell you to walk around randomly (mind your head for the walls!).  Now suppose I tell you that you are standing in yellow area. What is the probability that you are standing in the blue area as well? Well, $0$ of course! Since you know that there is no green area, that is overlap between the yellow and blue area. So the event "I have walked onto a blue area" depends on the event "I have walked onto a yellow area". I can give additional information about the probability of the former based on information about the latter.

Now for INDEPENDENCE: Suppose $\frac{1}{16}$ of the room is green and that 
the yellow area (green parts included) and blue area (green parts included) both still have area $\frac{1}{4}$.
I let you in the room (still blindfolded) you stumble around and suddenly I tell you that you are in the yellow area. Now I ask you the probability
that you are in the blue area. Since $\frac{1}{4}$ of the yellow area is 
also blue (that is the green part). You know that the probability of standing in the blue part in $1/4$. But one fourth of the entire room is also blue! So telling you that you are in the yellow part does not give you additional information about the blue part. You have a one in four shot to be in the blue part if I tell you that you are in the yellow part and a  one in four shot if I just tell you that you "just are somewhere in the room". There is no additional information to be derived about the event "I am in the blue part of the room" from the event "I am in the yellow part of the room". That is independence.

Comment: I have of course just made an explicit example of the second paragraph of ConMan's answer.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to  classify $2$ events $A$, $B$ is

**MUTUALLY EXCLUSIVE**
Both can't occur together:$\quad P[A ∩ B] = 0$ and $P[A ∪ B] = P[A] + P[B]$

**NOT MUTUALLY EXCLUSIVE**
Both can occur together: $\quad P[A ∪ B] = P[A] + P[B] - P[A ∩ B]$

further subdivided into

$(a)$ *INDEPENDENT*
Occurrence of one doesn't affect that of the other: $\quad P[A ∩ B] = P[A]\cdot P[B]$

$(b)$ *DEPENDENT*
Occurrence of one affects that of the other: $\quad P[A ∩ B] = P[A]\cdot P[B | A] = P[B]\cdot P[A | B]$

---

ADDED

There are exceptional circumstances in which the two events can be both mutually exclusive and independent, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126076/mutually-exclusive-and-independent-event-help-with-examples) at MSE

Comment: Events can be independent and mutually exclusive, for example $\varnothing$ is independent of every event $A$.

Comment: @Did: You are right, of course; only at a basic level I thought this much should suffice. I have now given OP a link.